# Display name instead of Id in Yii

Tags: yii

I want to display the name of Shift instead of shift_id

I have a dropboxlist from other table that is like this

```
<div>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mon'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'mon', CHtml::listData(
        Shift::model()->findAll(), 'shft_id', 'name'),
    array('prompt' => 'Select a Department')
); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'mon'); ?>
```

I have two tables that is
Day: id_day,mon,tues,wed,etc

Shift: shft_id,start,end,name,status

Here is the relation in the day

```
'shift'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Shift','shft_id'),
```

For Shift:

```
'day'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Day','id_day'),
```

It is already working. The choices in the dropbox was the name of the Shift, and puts the shft_id in the mon,tues,wed,etc. In the view of the form it looks like

id_user: 3

mon:5

tues:5

wed:6

what I wanted to be is that in the view.

id_user: 3

mon: 6am-5pm

tues: 7am-6pm

etc.etc.

I dont know what command it is. I have no idea. Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of  User::getusername() method.

I think you can simply use this in one line.

```
 // format models resulting using listData     
<?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'user_id', CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name')); ?>
```

Comment: sir it says. Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Well, User::getusername() such way of calling a function can be use in anywhere. And I guess it is pretty simple to understand for those yii's beginner.

Answer (score 1):

below is an example which I think may solved your problem

in **_form.php**

```
<?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'user_id', User::getusername()); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?></th>
```

in **User** model

```
public function getusername()
{
   $criteria2=new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria2->select='*';
   $quser=User::model()->findAll($criteria2);
   foreach($quser as $r) 
   {    
      $user_id= $r->user_id;
      $user_name=$r->user_name;

      $user_array[$user_id]=$user_name;
   }
   return $user_array;
}
```

Comment: it says include(CDBCriteria.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory. can you help me with this sir?

Comment: hey there. Please check your spelling.  [http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24666-includecdbcriteriaphp-error/](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24666-includecdbcriteriaphp-error/)

Comment: CD **b** not CD **B**

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what you are really asking. I believe you were saying that you are already able to populate your records correctly from the dropdowns. But when you are displaying, the view is only showing the shift_id value? The relation for the day should be able to get your shift name. How are you displaying the list:

```
mon: 5
tue: 5
wed: 6
```

I'm trying to understand if you need help displaying the dropdown items properly, or how to display the shift name later after the values have been set in the database.  Also, your 'Day' table has me confused. What are the field names? Are they 'day_id' and 'day'? Or do you actually name the fields after each day of the week?

If you are displaying the data through a `foreach` and are getting each day (let's assume it is `$day`) object, then the relationship to 'shift' can give you the name like this: `echo $day->shift->name;` if the name displays as '#am-#pm'. Otherwise you can display it like this:

`echo sprintf('%d a.m. - %d p.m.',$day->shift->start,$day->shift->end);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the people who helped me. It did lead me to the answer anyone who has the same problem here is what i did.

In my model/Day

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
       'monday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','mon'),
       'tuesday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','tue'),
       'wednesday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','wed'),
       'thursday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','thurs'),
       'friday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','fri'),
       'saturday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','sat'),
       'sunday'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Shift','sun'),



    );
}
```

and In my models/Shift

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(


        'day_mon' =>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','mon'),
        'day_tue' =>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','tue'),
        'day_wed' =>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','wed'),
        'day_thurs'=> array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','thurs'),
        'day_fri'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','fri'),
        'day_sat'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','sat'),
        'day_sun'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Day','sun'),
    );
}
```

The problem is with my relations. its not set properly, so you need to set it properly **then go to Day/view**

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id_day',
    array(
        'name'=>'mon',
        'value'=>CHtml::encode($model->monday->name)
    ),
```

**Here is the output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a detail veiw then use the following code:

widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
                'id',
                'name',
                 array(
                    'label' => $model->shift->getAttributeLabel('shift_name'),
                    'value' => $model->shift->shift_name
                ),)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else will be in my boat, what you will need to do is edit view.php in view/modelname/view.php

widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
                'id',
                'name',
                'country_id')); ?>

into

widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
                'id',
                'name',
                 array(
                    'label' => $model->country->getAttributeLabel('country'),
                    'value' => $model->country->name
                ),)); ?>